# Type the return of a function such that it contains keys that are elements in an argument array

Tags: typescript

So I have a function:

```
type Action = 'doX' | 'doY'
function canIPerform(actions: Action[]) : {[action: string]: Boolean} {
    // Some business logic
    return {'doX': true}
}
```

What I want is to type it such that the returned map only contains keys that were passed in the argument:

```
let x = canIPerform(['doX'])
// x should be typed as {[k in 'doX']: boolean}

let x = canIPerform(['doY', 'doX'])
// x should be typed as {[k in 'doX' | 'doY']: boolean}
```

The first problem is simply the fact that arrays are runtime, but I can kind of circumvent it by requiring that they be called using `const`:

```
let x = canIPerform(['doX', 'doY'] as const)
```

although I have found no way of "forcing" this. I tried a bunch of things, but I can't seem to find some equivalent of `keyof` that kind of works for tuples.

Comment: Have you tried using generics?

Comment: I can't understand `// x should be typed as {'doX' | 'doY': boolean}`. ts has not such type, `doX` and `doY` should be two different keys

Comment: @Nullndr - Sorry, I was thinking something along the lines of `{[k in 'doX' | 'doY'] : boolean}`

Comment: @RohanPrabhu try this `function foo<T extends Action>(args: T[]): { [K in T]: boolean };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your issue:

```js
type Action = 'doX' | 'doY'
function canIPerform<T extends Action[]>(actions: T) : Record<T[number], boolean> {
    // Some business logic
    return { [actions[0]]: true }
}
let x = canIPerform(['doX'])
//  ^?
// x should be typed as {[k in 'doX']: boolean}

let y = canIPerform(['doY', 'doX'])
//  ^?
// x should be typed as {[k in 'doX' | 'doY']: boolean}
```

`x` and `y` will functionally be equivalent to the types you have mentioned.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHZQLxQOQBNkAa2UAPjvgJrYBQAZgK6oIrpwCGqAkgAoQBOtZHwC2AHgAqUCAA9gEVLgDOsZmgDaAXQB8ACjarUigFxRxASigmAShDhDcEtanrCARvw0AaKK+TIANhAcWlAA3tRQkVAA9NFQAMrIwtCu9IqIqBCKyv7IAOaIcBFRfBDA9HzooVBq+khoimoADBoaJsB89NAAvtS9gcBQ0phQ7Fy8AkLCOmp4hNgaZtSxkQB6APzLccOKABbI9P64PtCgkMdsyqFqANZQGeTzbT5+gRy91ANQICNjPPyCEQzOZUbxzIiLLZrTYrHb7Q7HdxQM4QC5XW73dDg4hkEELEy+AJBVC9IA)

Comment: Yes! It absolutely does exactly what I was expecting - I looked up the docs and learnt about `T[number]` which is something I was unaware of. I still find it a bit unintuitive as to how that works, but `T[number]` happens to be exactly what I was looking for!